# subplot python Matplotlib not working with groupby().sum()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

in this piece of code I try to display the same plot 4 times in one figure.

```
faiGraficoBarh( parolePerAutore(dfPulito), 'message for every person','x','y', 2,2,1) 
faiGraficoBarh( parolePerAutore(dfPulito), 'message for every person','x','y', 2,2,2) 
faiGraficoBarh( parolePerAutore(dfPulito), 'message for every person','x','y', 2,2,3) 
faiGraficoBarh( parolePerAutore(dfPulito), 'message for every person','x','y', 2,2,4) 
plt.show()
```

the `parolePerAutoreMethod` return a dataFrame:

```
def parolePerAutore(df):
   return df[['author', 'wordCount', 'letterCount']].groupby('author').sum()
```

and the method `faiGraficoBarh` for making the plot is:

```
def faiGraficoBarh(table, titolo , x ,y, nrow, ncol, fig):
   plt.subplot(nrow,ncol,fig)
   table.head(10).plot.barh()
   plt.title(titolo)
   plt.xlabel(x)
   plt.ylabel(y)
```

the problem is that after `plt.show` it generate 5 figures: one containing the plot and 4 containing only the axes in the 4 different position.
[here an example of what I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojdqY.png)

Answer (score 0):

When you have multiple subplots, pandas plot needs an `ax` to draw on. The simplest solution would be to use the "current ax" as in `table.head(10).plot.barh(ax=plt.gca())`. The current ax is changed by the `plt.subplot()` command.

Note that the `subplot()` function is an old construct, similar to Matlab's. In newer versions of matplotlib there is [`plt.subplots`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) with easier to manage parameters, which creates both a figure and the axes.  There is also a parameter `gridspec_kw={'hspace': 0.4, 'wspace': 0.15})` with which you can control the spacing between the subplots. [`gridspec_kw=`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec.html#matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec) also allows to create subplots with different sizes. An interesting parameter to `plt.subplots` can be `sharex=True`, to make all your subplots have the same x-axis, so it would be easier to compare plots with different bar lengths.

You can use the construct as follows:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def faiGraficoBarh(table, titolo, x, y, ax):
    table.head(10).plot.barh(ax=ax)
    ax.set_title(titolo)
    ax.set_xlabel(x)
    ax.set_ylabel(y)

def parolePerAutore(dfPulito):
    return pd.DataFrame({'words': np.random.uniform(1, 10, 10), 'letters': np.random.uniform(1, 10, 10)},
                        index=list('ABCDEFGHIJ'))

dfPulito = None  # we're just working for dummy data

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(10, 5),
                         gridspec_kw={'hspace': 0.4, 'wspace': 0.15})

faiGraficoBarh(parolePerAutore(dfPulito), 'message for every person', 'x', 'y', axes[0][0])
faiGraficoBarh(parolePerAutore(dfPulito), 'message for every person', 'x', 'y', axes[0][1])
faiGraficoBarh(parolePerAutore(dfPulito), 'message for every person', 'x', 'y', axes[1][0])
faiGraficoBarh(parolePerAutore(dfPulito), 'message for every person', 'x', 'y', axes[1][1])

plt.show()
```

Comment: Was this answer helpful?